# Prove that $A$ is open when $A \cap bd(A) = \emptyset$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-writing

Before I saw the solution to the problem below, I was attempting to prove it using De Morgan's laws.

$bd(A)$ is the boundary of $A$, and $\overline A$ is the complement of $A$

**My attempt**

$\overline{A\cap bd(A)}=X$

and by De Morgan's laws

$\overline{A} \cup \overline {bd(A)}=X$

and by the definition of $bd(A)$ and another application of De Morgan

$\overline{A} \cup \overline {cl(A) \cap \overline{A}}=X$

$\overline{A} \cup \overline {cl(A)} \cup A=X$

where $cl(A)$ is the closure of $A$

I was unsure how to proceed from this point.  I was considering isolating $A$ by writing $A=X$\ $\overline A \cup \overline{cl(A)}$, but I wasn't sure if I could do this, and even if I could, I still don't see how I'd get that A is open.

Thanks, and here's the problem along with another solution for reference purposes

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is $bd(A)$? Do write $\overline{A}$ for the complement of $A$ in $X$? Hence $\overline{A}=X\setminus A$?

Comment: $bd(A)$ is the boundary of $A$ and yes, $\overline A$ is the complement as well as $X \setminus A$.  I've edited my question

Comment: @Chickenmancer but the conclusion is that $A$ is open.  Where did I assume this?

Comment: The very first line of your proof is that $\overline{A\cap bd(A)}=X.$

Comment: That follows directly from the condition given, as you pointed out in your previous comment

Comment: I misread the statement. My apologies.

Comment: The overline $\overline A$ in topology usually denotes the closure of $A.$ A fairly common symbol for  the complement of $A$ is $A^c.$ The most common notation for the boundary of $A$ is $\partial A$ ("\partial A") or Fr($A$). (Fr being short for Frontier).

Comment: In any space $X$ and any $A\subset X,$ the 3 sets $C=Int(A), $ $ D=bd(A)= \partial A=cl(A)\cap cl(X\setminus A), $ $ E= Int(X\setminus A)$are pair-wise disjoint and their union is $X. $  ( $ Int$ denotes interior). Since ( obviously) $A\cap E$ is empty, and $C\subset A,$ we have $A=(A\cap C)\cup (A\cap D)$ $=C\cup (A\cap D).$... So if $A\cap D$ is empty then $A=C=$ $Int(A),$ which is open because $Int(A)$ is defined as the union of all subsets of $A$ that are open in $X.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should use deMorgan's laws in this case. (At least, i don't see how to.)

It's easy just to note that any $a\in A$ has to have a nbhd that doesn't meet $X\setminus A$ by definition of boundary (as in the solution you included).

But, here's an alternate approach: 
 $\partial A=\partial A^c$.  Hence $A\cap\partial A=\emptyset\implies A\cap\partial A^c=\emptyset\implies \partial A^c\subset A^c\implies A^c$ is closed.  (This uses the sort of complementary fact that a set is closed iff it contains its boundary...)

Comment: Both approaches make sense, thanks!  I was also wondering if I wanted to isolate $A$, for example in the expression $\overline{A} \cup \overline {cl(A)} \cup A=X$ then would I write $A=X \setminus \overline A \cup \overline {cl(A)}$?  I'm not trying to make that proof work, just wanting to know how to perform operations on unions and intersections

Comment: Well, of course $A\subset \text{ cl }A\implies \overline{\text{ cl }A}\subset \bar A$.  Try using this to simplify matters.